# How do you scale about local axis, x in this case?

Tags: modeling

I would like to scale these down width wise, but even with Transformation Orientation set to Local and Pivot Center for Rotation and Scaling set to Individual Origins, scaling on x or Y turns them all according to the World Axis.
[image: Scaling locally]

Comment: Did you try using ALT+S -> X to scale along the face normals?
Edit - Hmm. I should have tested this first. I'm sure it used to be useful :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's the result you're after:

[image]

Try scaling around individual origins and hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to exclude the Z axis while you're at it.

Comment: Thank you.  I had the origins set correctly, but I was trying to scale on the x or y.  Shift+Z worked.  Thank you.

Comment: @eyeclick If the answer is correct, could you accept it?

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to figure out how to.

Comment: I won't complain. Happy blending